# Rearranging formula to find desired variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{n_2-n_1}{n_1\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right)}$$

How do I isolate $R_2$ onto the left side of the equation? So far, I know that I have to cross multiply first and then subtract $1/R_1$ on both sides. Then subtract $1/R_1$ from $f(n_2-n_1)/n_1$. However I'm confused as to what to do next. Could someone please explain step by step on how to get the answer? Thank you!

Comment: I have edited your question to make the formula clearer (based on what I guessed it was). Is that what was intended?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Always use MathJax for math formatting- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes, that was the equation I was going for. Thanks for editing it!

Answer (score 1):

Take it one step at a time. At each step, see what the first ("outermost") obstacle to $R_2$ being alone is, and deal with it. First get $R_2$ out from under the large fraction ("cross multiply") (If you are confident here, you can leave $n_1$ in the denominator and just multiply the bracket; I chose to remove the entire fraction)
$$
n_1\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right) = f(n_2-n_1)
$$ Then get $R_2$ out from the brackets
$$
\frac{n_1}{R_1}-\frac{n_1}{R_2}= f(n_2-n_1)
$$ Then get all the non-$R_2$ terms away from the side of the equation where $R_2$ is
$$
-\frac{n_1}{R_2}= f(n_2-n_1) - \frac{n_1}{R_1}
$$Then get $-n_1$ away from the fraction where $R_2$ is
$$
\frac1{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{f(n_2-n_1)}{n_1}
$$
Then get $R_2$ out from under the fraction (invert the whole shebang):
$$
R_2 = \frac{1}{\frac1{R_1} - \frac{f(n_2-n_1)}{n_1}} = \frac{R_1n_1}{n_1 - R_1f(n_2-n_1)}
$$